# Pull a specific substring out of a line in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, substring, list-comprehension

I have a file with many lines formatted as such:

`DIV ID=0X78800009 EXT="LOS ANGELES" TY=STANDARD OWN=0X74400002 ABBR=LA`

I need to pull out the EXT value, but only the part in quotes. I'm currently using this:

```
for line in file:
    if sub in line:
        extlist.append([item[4:] for item in line.split() if item.startswith('EXT=')].pop())
```

But it only appends the "LOS" part of LOS ANGELES to idlist. I'm a little new to python, but is there a way to wrap `item[4:]` in `str(item[4:])` and use [string functions](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html) to extract the value i need?

As a note, the text in the EXT field varies in length, they are all random city names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can be **sure** that there are no other double quotes in your line then this simple approach will work:

```
s='DIV ID=0X78800009 EXT="LOS ANGELES" TY=STANDARD OWN=0X74400002 ABBR=LA'

s.split('"')[1]
'LOS ANGELES'
```

Note that using a *[regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re)* is a more flexible/robust way to find this if the above constraints don't hold.

Otherwise this is one way to solve this problem in the spirit of *"Simple is better than complex."* (The Zen of Python).

Comment: nice, theres no other quotes anywhere so this works great! Thanks :) (i'll accept this once the timer goes away... haha)

Answer (score 4):

[Regular Expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re)

```
>>> import re
>>> myString = 'DIV ID=0X78800009 EXT="LOS ANGELES" TY=STANDARD OWN=0X74400002 ABBR=LA'
>>> re.search('EXT="(.+?)"',myString).group(1)
'LOS ANGELES'
```